# Writing ISO 19139 compliant XML metadata from spreadsheet?

Tags: python, xml, metadata, iso-19139

I am looking at a way to migrate the metadata from a spreadsheet into ISO 19139 compliant XML metadata documents for a collection of shapefiles. I can parse the data out of the spreadsheet into strings without issue however I am getting lost on how to take those strings and use them to populate the elements.

This example: http://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html covers most of what I want to do, however I would need to generate the tree beforehand based on the ISO 19139 schema. PyXB seems to have schema bundles for OpenGIS but I would like some insight on how to connect everything.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it is to generate a really simple XML tree for each record in your spreadsheet, write an XSLT stylesheet to translate from your simple XML to ISO 19139, then use [lxml.etree.XSLT](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt) to transform.

The major advantage of this is it keeps the complex iso19139 XML out of your python code which makes it much easier to debug.  Some more info/tutorials on xslt [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-introxslt/).

Here's some example code:

```
from lxml import etree
import os.path

def list_to_xml(datalist,rootname):
    '''Transform a metadata record to a flat XML string'''

    root = etree.Element(rootname)

    for fld in datalist:
        col=fld[0]
        dat=str(fld[1]) # may need to be careful of unicode encoding issues
                        # when reading data from Excel

        child=etree.SubElement(root,col)
        child.text=dat

    return root

def transform(inxml,xslfile):
    xslfile=os.path.abspath(xslfile).replace('\\','/') #xslt doesn't like backslashes in absolute paths...
    xsl = etree.parse(xslfile)
    xslt = etree.XSLT(xsl)
    return xslt(inxml)

xslfile = 'test.xslt'

#Column headers from the Excel spreadsheet
header=['column1','xmin','ymin','xmax','ymax','thelastcolumn']

#Data pulled out of the spreadsheet
#You would loop over all rows and do a transform on each row
row=['A value',1.2345,5.4321,2.3456,6.5432,'last value']

inxml = list_to_xml(zip(header,row),"ExcelMetadata")
print etree.tostring(inxml)

#The above prints - <ExcelMetadata><column1>A value</column1><xmin>1.2345</xmin><ymin>5.4321</ymin><xmax>2.3456</xmax><ymax>6.5432</ymax><thelastcolumn>last value</thelastcolumn></ExcelMetadata>

iso19139 = transform(inxml,xslfile)
print str(iso19139)
```

The 'test.xslt' stylesheet referred to in the above code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
  xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" 
  xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" 
  xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" 
  xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" 
  xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" 
  xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" 
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/ExcelMetadata">

      <gmd:fileIdentifier>
        <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="column1"/></gco:CharacterString>
      </gmd:fileIdentifier>

      <!-- Lots of other xml stuff -->

      <xsl:if test="normalize-space(thelastcolumn)">
        <gmd:someelement>
          <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="thelastcolumn"/></gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:someelement>
      </xsl:if>

      <gmd:identificationInfo>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
          <gmd:extent>
            <gmd:EX_Extent>
              <gmd:geographicElement>
                <gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                  <gmd:extentTypeCode>
                    <gco:Boolean>1</gco:Boolean>
                  </gmd:extentTypeCode>
                  <gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                    <gco:Decimal><xsl:value-of select="xmin"/></gco:Decimal>
                  </gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                  <gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                    <gco:Decimal><xsl:value-of select="xmax"/></gco:Decimal>
                  </gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                  <gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                    <gco:Decimal><xsl:value-of select="ymin"/></gco:Decimal>
                  </gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                  <gmd:northBoundLatitude>
                    <gco:Decimal><xsl:value-of select="ymax"/></gco:Decimal>
                  </gmd:northBoundLatitude>
                </gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
              </gmd:geographicElement>
            </gmd:EX_Extent>
          </gmd:extent>
        </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
      </gmd:identificationInfo>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```