# Creating ISO 19139 xml metadata from spreadsheet?

Tags: python, xml, metadata, iso-19115, iso-19139

I have metadata that was collected according to ISO categories and is currently housed in a spreadsheet where each row houses metadata for a GIS dataset.  I am interested in automating the creation of XML metadata from this spreadsheet.  A similar question ([Writing ISO 19139 compliant XML metadata from spreadsheet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60705)) was asked a few years ago, but I'm hoping that someone may have found a better way! A solution that uses Python or R scripting to create the XML files would be great!

Comment: As it stands I think your question, which seems near identical to the duplicate is too broad (it says what you want to do but not precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck) and as an XML writing question it *may* be more suited to [so] than here even once focussed.  As someone with the rep of 50+ [comment everywhere privilege](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) I think you should make a comment on the duplicate question, or be prepared to provide a lot more detail about what you have tried and where you are stuck here.

Comment: Perhaps you could rephrase your question to focus on the automation of converting rows in a spreadsheet to XML documents.